# JQuery - Hide a parent div that always has the same class IF it contains another div with another class that repeats itself that contains 2017

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page with multiple divs like this:

```
`<div class="mod-tile">
Bla bla zbing
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
<time class="date">Crocodile Dundee 2016</time>
<div class="date">Lorem lorena 2017</div>
</div>

<div class="mod-tile">
Bla bla zbing
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
<time class="date">John Humdee 2016</time>
<div class="date">Izabelle Adjani 2018</div>
</div>

<div class="mod-tile">
Bla bla zbing
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
<time class="date">Rabbit wabbit 2017</time>
<div class="date">Bam boom 2020</div>
</div>`
```

How can I hide, using JQuery, the parent "mod-tile" div if the child div with class "date" contains 2017 as text?  Only the "mod-tile" div that contains that, not all other "mod-tile" divs.

My limited knowledge try:

```
$("div:hasClass("mod-tile"):has(div:hasClass("date"):contains("2017")).hide()")
```

Thank you

EDIT:
So the solution for the above divs is, as mr. Paul T. said:

```
$(".mod-tile > div.date:contains('2017')").parent().hide();
```

What happens if the "date" div is nested within another div, and we still need to hide the grandparent "mod-tile"?

```
<div class="mod-tile">
Bla bla zbing
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="wabbit">
    <time class="date">Crocodile Dundee 2016</time>
    <div class="date">Lorem lorena 2017</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Solution for second example, based on Paul's code and using Rory's suggestions:

```
$(".mod-tile").has("div.date:contains('2016')").hide();
```

Thank you

Comment: Use the [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector) and [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector) selectors. If you need more specific help, please edit the question to show your attempt so we can help you to debug it

Comment: To be honest I have limited knowledge of Jquery, I have added my try in the OP. I used hasClass to check class, has to check for a child div with class date. Thank you for the help. PS: My code definitely doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `>` selector to the child `div`'s having the `date` class within the parent, and then hide the parent:

```js
// Find child div.date elements that contains the data and then hide the parent.

$(".mod-tile > div.date:contains('2017')").parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mod-tile">
    Bla bla zbing
    <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <time class="date">Crocodile Dundee 2016</time>
    <div class="date">Lorem lorena 2017</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="mod-tile">
    Bla bla zbing
    <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <time class="date">John Humdee 2016</time>
    <div class="date">Izabelle Adjani 2018</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="mod-tile">
    Bla bla zbing
    <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <time class="date">Rabbit wabbit 2017</time>
    <div class="date">Bam boom 2020</div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

Seeing your second example made me realize that `has()` could have been used with the first example too, in the same way, and not need to call the `parent()`. I have never used `has()` before, so I learned something new too!

```js
// Find child div.date elements that contains the data to hide the parent.

$('.mod-tile').has("div.date:contains('2017')").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mod-tile">
    Bla bla zbing
    <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <time class="date">Crocodile Dundee 2016</time>
    <div class="date">Lorem lorena 2017</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="mod-tile">
    Bla bla zbing
    <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <time class="date">John Humdee 2016</time>
    <div class="date">Izabelle Adjani 2018</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="mod-tile">
    Bla bla zbing
    <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <time class="date">Rabbit wabbit 2017</time>
    <div class="date">Bam boom 2020</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! One more question if you have the time. I have edited the OP at the bottom with the example. What happens when the "date" div is nested within another div, so the parent "mod-tile" becomes grandparent? Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much! I did it based on your code. Example in OP.

Comment: Cheer cheers!  You learned something new, for me everything was new :)) Thanks again.